# Assign custom properties to a node in TreeView windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, properties, treeview, nodes

Say I have a TreeView of cars with different manufacturers, then a sub tree of models, etc. If I want each node to have a set of properties how would I do that? Would I make a new class and then assign each node to a class in some way? I'm having difficulty conceptualizing this but I imagine it is possible. What would be the point of a TreeView if you couldn't add data to each member?

In my right click menu for the carModelNode I have an option called properties. When the user clicks it it opens a form where the user then enters/edits data such as the year of the car, colour, manual/auto, etc. How can I then store that data and associate it with that node? Is there an easy way to do this or is this going to call for more of a jerry rigged approach?

**Please provide some examples with what you're talking about because I'm still not very good with syntax!

EDIT: my attempt below is for @Ed Plunkett

A class with the properties I want each node to have:

```
public class CarProperties
{
    public string type = "";
    public string name = "";
    public int year = 0;
    public bool isManual = false;
}
```

And now trying to assign these properties to a node:

```
CarProperties FordFocus = new CarProperties();
FordFocus.name = "exampleName";
...
treeIO.SelectedNode.Tag = FordFocus;
```

Does this look about right?

Comment: You can assign an instance of any arbitrary class (or any other value)  to a TreeViewItem's `Tag` property. It's there for this purpose. I'm not going to bother writing a complete useful example for you because I don't have the time. If you provide any code, I'll modify that to show how it's done.

Comment: @EdPlunkett See anything wrong with my attempt above? I posted it under my original question.

Comment: That should work fine.

Comment: Your CarProperties class has four *fields*, not four *properties*.  See [What is the difference between a Field and a Property in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/295104/719186)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two ways to do this: The simplest way is to use the `Tag` property of `TreeNode`.

```
public Form1()
{

    InitializeComponent();

    //  Horrible example code -- in real life you'd have a method for this
    foreach (var car in cars)
    {
        var tn = new TreeNode(car.name)
        {
            Tag = car
        };

        treeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);
    }
}

public List<CarProperties> cars = new List<CarProperties>()
{
    new CarProperties() { name = "Ford Focus" },
    new CarProperties() { name = "TVR Tamora" },
    new CarProperties() { name = "Toyota Tacoma" },
};

private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    //  This is a "cast": IF e.Node.Tag is actually an instance of CarProperties,
    //  the "as" operator converts it to a reference of that type, we assign 
    //  that to the variable "car", and now you can use it's properties and methods. 
    var car = e.Node.Tag as CarProperties;

    MessageBox.Show("Selected car " + car.name);
}
```

Comment: Is the list stuff 100% necessary? it's confusing me a decent amount but I think I'm getting it a bit? Can you explain what you're doing when you add the " : TreeNode" to the end of your class declaration for CarTreeNode?Also what's the treeView1_AfterSelect for? Thanks for your patience

Comment: @CapnJack `treeView1_AfterSelect` is an "event handler". Double click on the `TreeView` in the form designer and by default, it will create an `AfterSelect` handler for you just like mine. That handler method is called every time the user clicks the mouse on a tree node. I used it to show you how to get the `CarProperties` out of the `TreeNode`.

Comment: okay it's making a lot more sense now. Thanks for the explanation about inheritance. Always wondered what that was.

Comment: have a good one in mind? I did this one: http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/CSharpFundamentals.aspx and couldn't find anything on code academy.

Comment: Yeah I'm currently on coop and learning through trial and error. That's the best way I find because you only learn what you use. I'm just going to stick to projects and assignments with help from friends I think. tutorials waste a lot of time on common things. Back to the question though can we talk about this part of the code?:
    "var car = e.Node.Tag as CarProperties;" Is var just a typless variable? This is the part I needed so I want to make sure I'm understanding 100% what this does.